# Detect when child control resizes?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, vcl

Is there a way for a parent control to detect when a child control resizes? I'm considering writing a panel control that resizes as it's child controls resize (similar to the way a HTML DIV element will expand to fit it's contents).

Comment: There has to be a way. Have a look at TPanel or TForm sources. The property AutoSize enables this behavior to them

Comment: `TPanel` simply inherits and promotes the `TControl.AutoSize` property. `TControl` does all of the actual work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Surely not *all* the work, because only descendants of `TWinControl` can have child controls at the first place.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: no, `TControl` does not do everything, `TWinControl` contributes as well.  But `TControl` does expose autosize-related virtual methods that `TWinControl` overrides so it can adjust for client area, anchors, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your actual question, I beleve that the `AlignControls` method of your windowed control is called when a child control is resized or moved.

Comment: Indeed, `TControl.SetBounds` calls `RequestAlign` leading the parent's `AlignControls` to be called.

Comment: `AlignControl()` and `AlignControls()` are meant for aligning the parent's other child controls relative to the specified child control.  After aligning, the parent's `CanAutoSize()` and `CanResize()` methods are called to resize the parent itself if `AutoSize` is true.

Answer (score 4):

`TControl` and `TWinControl` have built-in support for handling auto-sizing for you.  All you have to do is set the `TControl.AutoSize` property to True.  It is declared as `protected` in `TControl`, so you will have to promote it to `public` or `published` if you want your component users to set it.  Otherwise, just set it in your component's contructor.

You can override the virtual `CanAutoSize()` method if you want to customize how your parent control sizes itself relative to its children.

Comment: It does not scale well. For example, i may have a form with alTop panel with settings and alClient panel below it on Auto-Size form.
If top panel may be shown/hidden or may change its height die to some events - that makes the form shrink more and more :-(